# what methods are in winio64.dll and how to use them

Tags: java, c++, dll

I need to learn how to use winio64.dll, however its founder's website is being updated & I could see nothing. Basically I want to simulate key board strikes in Java, however JNI C++ dll using SendInput or keybd_event does not work in my case. I heard that winio64.dll had some native methods that can do this kind of job. I searched a lot & unable to find a tutorial on how to use Winio64.dll. Thank in advance.

Comment: Why? Normally you have not a technical but a *functional* requirement.

Comment: I want to simulate a key strikes to enter text into a <object>...</object> html element. I don't know why general functions such as Java Robot class or C++ dll SendInput keybd_event does not work even though they work in some text input html element.

Answer (score 1):

List of exported functions are:

```
InitializeWinIo
ShutdownWinIo
MapPhysToLin
UnmapPhysicalMemory
GetPhysLong
SetPhysLong
GetPortVal
SetPortVal
InstallWinIoDriver
RemoveWinIoDriver
```

You can use it with standard LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

here is a nice example (with functions signatures):
http://matrix207.github.io/2012/09/16/winio-sample/

EDIT: This example is in C. If you need in Java, you can search for "GetProcAddress in Java" and you will find a lot of example how to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mligor. How could I simulate key strikes from this list?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @mligor. After some research I have written a JNI based C++ code to simulate key strikes, there are some coding work to do. The key function here is: SetPortVal, the key board port is X60, X64